# MySQL query to know schedule compliance

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp

I have a table **Works** where I got the columns ***start_date*** and ***end_date*** which are datetime types and ***qtty*** tinyint. For covering those works I got another table named **Turns** which has ***start_turn*** and ***end_turn*** both datetime types too.

The works needs to be covered for a number of people (who are assigned the turns) greater than or equal to ***qtty***, but the turns not necessarily need to be from ***works.start_date*** to ***works.end_date***.

What I need to know is if the works are covered properly, I mean if the works are always covered for at least ***qtty*** people from ***start_date*** to ***end_date***.

For example: CASE 1

Work => ***start_date*** = 2018-07-01 10:00 | ***end_date*** = 2018-07-01 22:00 | ***qtty*** = 2
Turns =>
Person A: ***start_turn*** = 2018-07-01 10:00 | ***end_turn*** = 2018-07-01 22:00
Person B: ***start_turn*** = 2018-07-01 10:00 | ***end_turn*** = 2018-07-01 16:00
Person C: ***start_turn*** = 2018-07-01 16:00 | ***end_turn*** = 2018-07-01 22:00

CASE 2

Work => ***start_date*** = 2018-07-01 10:00 | ***end_date*** = 2018-07-01 22:00 | ***qtty*** = 2
Turns =>
Person A: ***start_turn*** = 2018-07-01 10:00 | ***end_turn*** = 2018-07-01 22:00
Person B: ***start_turn*** = 2018-07-01 16:00 | ***end_turn*** = 2018-07-01 22:00
Person C: ***start_turn*** = 2018-07-01 16:00 | ***end_turn*** = 2018-07-01 22:00

Seeing the first case we could resolve it just extracting the minutes of the work multiply it by ***qtty*** and then compare that value with the sum of the minutes of each turn, and then the answer is YES, the work is covered properly. But applying this method to the second case the answer is YES too, but it's incorrect 'cause the work is not covered for at least two persons from ***start_date*** to ***end_date***.

How could I make it? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is the correct SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c53d1b

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Ok I added a SQL fiddle.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef328b/4 ... or something like that

Comment: Thanks for the reply Strawberry. But I'm so sorry, I have made a mistake in the foreign keys of the insert statements in the SQL Fiddle. I just updated the SQL Fiddle, if you can see it again it would be great.

Comment: The errors were on the "CASE 2" BEFORE: `insert into turns values (4, 1, '2018-08-01 10:00', '2018-08-01 22:00');` NOW: `insert into turns values (4, 2, '2018-08-01 10:00', '2018-08-01 22:00');`

Comment: That line is just one work that needs to be covered with the turns below, the other line/work is `insert into works values (2, '2018-08-01 10:00', '2018-08-01 22:00', 2);` which has its corresponding turns below. The Case 1 is properly covered but the Case 2 not.

Comment: OK, maybe it's the heat, but I still don't get it. Case 2 seems adequately covered !?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer, just a rough idea.

In order to solve this problem you have to think out of the box and formulate the problem in a slightly different way.

1. First you need to make a list of all the points in time regarding
   your **working interval** and its corresponding **turns**/**shifts**
2. Then you have to remove the duplicates - i.e. leave only the distinct points in time
3. Then you have to build a list with all the time intervals between these points in time - you will have N-1 intervals if you have N points in time
4. Then for each of the above intervals you need to count how many of the **turns**/**shifts** contain this interval completely
5. If for **each** of the above intervals you have at least **qtty** covering turns - then this **work** is fully covered by the shifts, otherwise it is not

Let's take your two example cases. For case 1 you have 3 points in time - 10, 16, 22. This means 2 intervals - from 10 to 16 and from 16 to 22. For the first interval you have 2 turns which completely contain the interval - A and B. For the second interval you have 2 turns which completely contain the interval - A and C.

For case 2 you have the same points in time and the same sub-intervals. However, this time for interval 10-16 you have only 1 turn which completely containts the interval - turn A. So for this case your **work** is not fully covered by the required number of **turns**.

I am still not sure how this can be implemented in a single SQL query - perhaps you will have to start with a stored procedure doing the things in procedural way with loop(s) and then refine it when you get a better understanding of the idea.

## UPDATE

Here is some SQL to give you the initial approximation, you will tweak it according to your taste (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72e841/3):

```
select * from
  (select p_start,p_end,qty -
    (select count(*) from turns 
      where start_turn <= p_start 
        and end_turn >= p_end
    ) as non_covered
   from
   (select pt, @start:=@end AS p_start, @end:=pt AS p_end 
     from
     (select start_date as pt from work where id=1
      union 
      select end_date as pt from work where id=1
      union 
      select start_turn from turns, work 
        where work.id=1 
          and start_turn between start_date and end_date
      union 
      select end_turn from turns, work 
        where work.id=1 
          and start_turn between start_date and end_date
     ) as tmp
     order by pt
   ) as period
   join work on work.id = 1
   where p_start <> p_end
  ) as cover
  where non_covered > 0
```

Comment: Thanks IVO that's a good idea. I'm used to using Stored Procedures, but I never did it with loops, what do you think about the performance? I have to show this info in real-time to watch if the employees are properly assigned.

Comment: You first need to build a solution which returns the right results - and only then bother how to optimize it. Points 1 and 2 are one subquery with DISTINCT, point 3 will need a window function to access the previous row in the above subquery, point 4 is the outer query which contains the above subquery and looks for the relevant turns, point 5 is the right side of the >= test (point 4 was the left). It is a non-trivial query but certainly achievable once you know the algorithm

Comment: Can you please make the whole query you mention? I am a little confused and I couldn't get it yet.

Comment: Thanks so much IVO, it works like a charm. You're great.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer; too long for a comment:

```
Case 1 : Qtty = 2


   10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
A  |------------------------------------|
B  |------------------|
C                     |-----------------|

Case 2 : Qtty = 2

   10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
A  |------------------------------------|
B                     |-----------------|
C                     |-----------------|
```

Case 2 seems to satisfy the requirement that 'those works not necessarily need to be covered from works.start_date to works.end_date'

Comment: Exactly but Case 2 doesn't satisfy the requirement of being covered for at least Qtty=2 people from works.start_date to works.end_date, I mind all the time from start to end.

Comment: OK, but that appears to contradict the previous statement.

Comment: The statements don't contradict, just see the Case 1, B and C don't have a Full Turn but the work is always covered for at least two people.

Comment: I suppose you mean to say 'where no one individual covers necessarily covers a full term, but where a full term is covered by at least qtty individuals'

Comment: Exactly that's the goal. Maybe I wrote it bad the 'those works not necessarily need to be covered from works.start_date to works.end_date' when it had to be 'the turns not necessarily have to be full turns'.